# How to download ubuntu to a windows 2000 computer using the cmd

Tags: bootloader

How can i use the the windows 2000 cmd line to download and install a version of ubuntu so i can be done with windows completely

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line

Comment: windows 2000 also came with perl (on install media; not installed by default as I recall for desktops) which allowed for it too

Comment: Can i possibly get one of you to email me directly or personal message me somehow i do not have reputation to use the live chat amd im not fully understanding

Comment: @AshleyKeidel I closed your question as off-topic, because what you are asking is how to download any file from a Windows 2000 CMD, which has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You may ask your question on [su] instead where Windows questions are on-topic. Note that the question linked above already covers your problem though, so please read that first. You are still very welcome to ask question as about Ubuntu here later though. And no, asking people to contact you directly off-site is not something we appreciate here. You can respond in the comment section just fine. Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a windows build of wget
https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

Then `wget https://something.org/afile.iso`

[image: wget-screenshot.png]